# Tailwind import failed

Tags: sass, next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

> Hi,

I'm trying to build an app using Tailwind and NextJs with some style in SCSS. Everything was working find and I was tweaking some Tailwind class in my components until the app suddenly crashed with this message

> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[10].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[10].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[10].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[10].use[4]!./styles/globals.scss
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')

It appeared just like this, it worked for 3 hours and then just stopped, I did not changed any config files or anything else. I don't understand. After some time looking trough my code I've found that if I remove these import at the top of my global.scss the app works fine, but I don't know where this undefined variable is..

> @tailwind base;
> @tailwind components;
> @tailwind utilities;

here is my tailwind config

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '2/3': '66.666667%',
      },
      colors: {
        'lavander-grey': '#625F63',
        'lavander-indigo': '#9893DA'

      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],

};
```

```
package.json
```

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0"
  },
  "engineStrict": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.0.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.2",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "swr": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
```

Postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
}
```

```
thanks for your help


I've tried to install some older Tailwind packages, wiped node_modules, made sure this was not my components the culprit, tried some Tailwind configurations,started a fresh dev server, did some intense googling
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to write those:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

you need to install `postcss`. 'postcss` is like webpack, uses plugins and evaluates them to modern CSS syntax that browser understand

```
 npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer postcss-nesting
```

Then you should have `postcss.config.js` and have this config:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["tailwindcss", "postcss-nesting", "autoprefixer"],
};
```

Comment: thanks @Yilmaz but look at my package.json, I already have PostCSS version 8.4.19

Comment: I've downgraded to     "postcss": "^8.3.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7" for now, it's working

Comment: @SuperPanda did you have `postcss.config.js` file

Comment: Yes i've edited my first post to include it thanks @Yilmaz

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind is no longer using PurgeCSS under the hood with the release of their JIT compiler as of Tailwind 3.0.

Update the first line of your config to:

```
content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

As shown in the docs, and be sure to include a `postcss.config.js` file.

Comment: thanks @Tim , for your reply, i've updated my config file like you said and it still does not work, and I already have a postcss config file wich looks like this

`
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
}

`